# Rails where clause with associations and multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have the following `select` statement:

```
requests = Request.select { |x| (x.name_rel == user || x.customer_rel == user || x.users.include?(user))
```

Basically I'm trying to get all `requests` for a single `user` where `requests` have the following relations:

```
  belongs_to :name_rel, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'name_id'
  belongs_to :customer_rel, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'customer_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

I understand `select` is a very bad way to do this, but I'm unsure of how to make `where` work with such a complex operation. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this in where condition like following

```
»  Request.where("name_id = ? OR customer_id =? OR (name_id IN (?) && customer_id IN (?))", user, user, [ids], [ids])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!